# Button inside UITableViewCell prevents scrolling only in iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I have a custom `UIButton` inside a custom `UITableViewCell` which was working on all versions and devices until I test it on `iOS8`.

When you try to scroll the table over the button it works (scrolls) on all devices and on all iOS versions except iOS8.

I for sure played with

`_tableViewController.tableView.canCancelContentTouches=YES;
 _tableViewController.tableView.delaysContentTouches=YES;`

But nothing changes.

Did something change especially related to touches or scrollviews, or... on `iOS8`?

**update**

Strangely, replacing `UIView` with `UIScrollView` (adding the following codes to the viewcontroller) solved the problem. I still don't know why this is required in iOS8.

```
-(void)loadView{
    UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1)];
    self.view=scrollView;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Please clear it.

Comment: When you try to scroll the table over the button it work (scrolls) on all devices and on all iOS versions but iOS8+iPad.

Comment: Can u read your comment again please and try to be a simple reader who doesn't know you problem, Do u understand yourself???

Comment: Can u please show the code u added the button. And the init code for your custom button.

Comment: I found out that this is not iPad specific but iOS specific.. Replacing `UIViewController`'s view with a `UIScrollView` solved the problem on iOS8, but I don't know why the table requires a parent `UIScrollView`.

Comment: `UITableView` includes `UIScrollView`, I mean, as a property of `UIScrollView`